# Sendmail/postfix mail not sending from local Mac OS X (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, email

I'm trying to get sendmail/postfix working properly on my iMac (10.9.2). I have a php web application I'm trying to test locally and it needs to send mail.

Even when testing this directly:

`date | mail -s test myEmail@gmail.com`

The mail never arrives, even as spam. In the logs, I'm seeing tons of "operation timed out" errors for contacting google/gmail:

```
Mar 17 10:57:13 imac.helion3.com postfix/postfix-script[10924]: starting the Postfix mail system
Mar 17 10:57:13 imac.helion3.com postfix/master[10925]: daemon started -- version 2.9.4, configuration /etc/postfix
Mar 17 10:57:13 imac.helion3.com postfix/qmgr[10933]: 012175629F9F: from=<daemon@localhost.localhost>, size=352, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 10:57:16 imac.helion3.com postfix/pickup[10932]: 94BBF562A0B2: uid=501 from=<botskonet>
Mar 17 10:57:16 imac.helion3.com postfix/cleanup[10948]: 94BBF562A0B2: message-id=<20140317175716.94BBF562A0B2@localhost>
Mar 17 10:57:16 imac.helion3.com postfix/qmgr[10933]: 94BBF562A0B2: from=<botskonet@localhost.localhost>, size=310, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 10:57:43 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10937]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.27]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:57:46 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10951]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:58:13 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10937]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.193.27]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:58:16 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10951]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.193.27]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:58:43 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10937]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.196.26]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:58:46 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10951]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.196.27]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:59:13 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10937]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.76.27]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:59:16 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10951]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.29.26]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:59:43 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10937]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.131.27]:25: Operation timed out
Mar 17 10:59:43 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10937]: 012175629F9F: to=<myEmail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=689, delays=538/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.131.27]:25: Operation timed out)
Mar 17 10:59:46 imac.helion3.com postfix/smtp[10951]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.75.27]:25: Operation timed out
```

I've run through the recommended postfix perms commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

I've configured postfix to use ipv4 after seeing ipv6 errors in the logs. This is for testing something locally anyway so I don't mind.

I've configured php to use:

`sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

Even though my current tests don't involve php.

Comment: should this be migrated to serverfault?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears port 25 is blocked (either from your ISP or possibly on your end):

`google.com[74.125.131.27]:25: Operation timed out`

Open Terminal and paste:

```
(echo >/dev/tcp/localhost/25) &>/dev/null && echo "TCP port 25 opened" || echo "TCP port 25 closed"
```

This should indicate whether or not port 25 is opened on your machine. If the port is closed you'll obviously need to open it.

Another useful command is:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

Which will indicate all of the open ports and connections currently active.

Since you haven't provided any info about your configuration itself I can only speculate what your relayhost is set as. If it's google, then try setting the port to `587`:

```
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Often ISP's block port 25 by default since it's commonly used by spammers.

> EDIT: It was determined that two things had to be taken into
>   consideration for this scenario:
>
> 1. The postfix mailserver was using a dynamic ip
> 2. The mailserver is hosted with an ISP that blocks port 25
>
> The fix was to use a relay server, which involved updating the postfix
>   main.cf with the additions of the relay host information and authentication
>   flags. The default submission port was changed to use 587 to bypass the isp block.

Comment: With these commands it seems port 25 is open, and I have no relayhost configured. The test email address I'm trying to send to, is an @gmail.com address. I have posted the output and my full postfix configs here: https://pste.me/#/SAWrU

Comment: Try `telenet localhost 25` from Terminal; it should be successful based on port 25 being open. Next, try doing `telnet relay-test.mail-abuse.org`, which tests to see if an outsider can reach you. Depending upon the outcome of that should determine whether or not your ISP blocks port 25. In Addition to running those tests, you can uncomment `#debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1` in your config file to increase the verbosity of logging with localhost.

Comment: Ah! I think that I've spotted your issue. By default OS X only allows inet_interfaces to loopback-only. You should try changing it to be `inet_interfaces = localhost` or `all` at the very end of your config.

Comment: Hmm, so far these changes don't seem to fix anything. Here's the output of the above commands and logs after I changed these configs and rebooted postfix: https://pste.me/#/kiSDW

Comment: It appears the ISP is blocking port 25, since you've now got everything else setup properly from what I can see. Try changing the submission port to determine if that is indeed the issue. I think that covers all the bases, except one final note — ensure that `/etc/hostconfig` is set to `MAILSERVER=-YES-`.

Comment: The `hostconfig` setting is correct, how would I go about changing the submission port?

Comment: Open `/etc/postfix/master.cf` then uncomment the line `#submission inet n – n – – smtpd` and save. Then allow access through your router/firewall by setting up port forwarding for port 587.

Comment: That option was already uncommented, I've port-forwarded 587 to my system, rebooted postfix just in case, but am still seeing the same errors: `postfix/smtp[18692]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.196.27]:25: Operation timed out`

Comment: It looks to still be using port 25 there, notice the port on the end - [74.125.196.27]:`25`.

Comment: How do I change what it's using? Here's my postfix master.cf: https://pste.me/#/TNhct

Comment: look in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and let me know if you see a port in there `[smtp.google.com] username:password`, if not just add it like this: `[smtp.google.com]:587 username:password`.

Comment: That file is completely empty, should I add something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49986/discussion-between-helion3-and-lll)