# AMPPS Mail on OS X

Tags: php, macos, email, ampps

I have been running AMPPS (Softaculous AMPPS) on OS X from version 10.9-10.11 (Mavericks to El Capitan) and have never had to configure any email settings in order for the PHP mail() function to work.

Here is the mail section of my php.ini:

```
    [mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/smtp
    SMTP = localhost
    ; http://php.net/smtp-port
    smtp_port = 25

    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
    ;sendmail_from = me@example.com

    ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-path
    ;sendmail_path =

    ; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
    ; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
    ; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
    ;mail.force_extra_parameters =

    ; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
    mail.add_x_header = On

    ; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
    ; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
    ;mail.log =
    ; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
    ;mail.log = syslog
```

My question is, how, or where are the emails being sent from? I have never configured AMPPS in any way to send emails. They just seem to work.

The reason I am asking is, I am trying to setup AMPPS on a local network server but cannot get emails to send even after configuring the smpt email settings with my gmail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that OS X comes with postfix preinstalled, that is why I don't need to setup SMTP settings for PHP.

However, with my PC problem, and to avoid any more hassle I just install hMailServer on my  windows local server and the PHP mail() function sends emails perfectly.

Comment: if you register to a site on my localhost it says a verification email, the email shows up in  a file in a file at vim /var/mail/USER but can not figure out how to get the email to send from the local host to the gmail server.

Comment: What OS are you using? Linux, or OS X?

Comment: Make sure that port 25 is not blocked in your internet connection, by either your ISP or router. If it is blocked, it will prohibit emails from going outside of you LAN.

Comment: Check this out: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461966/sendmail-postfix-mail-not-sending-from-local-mac-os-x-mountain-lion)

Comment: My port 25 is open, ;/